# React Issue - Child state changes the parent's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

**Question :**

If every component has its own state, then how this thing is happening,
Ho its possible that child is changing the state of parent ?

---

**Here is the full Code of my app:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
import Chip from 'material-ui/Chip';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const vehicles = [{value : 1 , label : 'Vehicle 1'},{value : 2 , label : 'Vehicle 2'},{value : 3 , label : 'Vehicle 3'},{value : 4 , label : 'Vehicle 4'},{value : 5 , label : 'Vehicle 5'},{value : 6 , label : 'Vehicle 6'},{value : 7 , label : 'Vehicle 7'},{value : 8 , label : 'Vehicle 8'}];
    this.state = {
      vehicles,
      name: 'React',
      name1: 'React1',
      name2: 'React2'
    };
  }

  render() {
    const dataSourceConfig = {
            text: 'label',
            value: 'value',
        };
    return (
      <div>
      <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div>
              <AutoCompleteHlpr 
              dataSource={this.state.vehicles} 
              dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}
              floatingLabelText='Select Vehicles'
              selectedOption={this.handleSelectedVehicle}/>

              <AutoCompleteHlpr 
              dataSource={this.state.vehicles} 
              dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}
              floatingLabelText='Select Vehicles'
              selectedOption={this.handleSelectedVehicle}/>

              <AutoCompleteHlpr 
              dataSource={this.state.vehicles} 
              dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}
              floatingLabelText='Select Vehicles'
              selectedOption={this.handleSelectedVehicle}/>
            </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}




export class AutoCompleteHlpr extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {dataSource : this.props.dataSource , searchText : ''};

        this.styles = {
            chip: {
                margin: 4,
            },
            wrapper: {
                display: 'flex',
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
            },
        };

        this.handleNewRequest = this.handleNewRequest.bind(this);
        this.getDataSource = this.getDataSource.bind(this);
        console.log(this.state);
    }

    handleNewRequest(searchText , index){
        this.state.dataSource[index]['selected'] = true;
        this.setState({dataSource : this.state.dataSource , searchText : '' });
        this.props.selectedOption(this.state.dataSource[index] , this.state.dataSource);
    }

    renderChip(data , index) {
        if(data.selected) {
            var value = this.props.dataSourceConfig.text ? this.props.dataSourceConfig.text : 'text';
            var key = this.props.dataSourceConfig.value ? this.props.dataSourceConfig.value : 'value';
            return (
                <Chip
                    key={data[key]}
                    style={this.styles.chip}
                    onRequestDelete={() => this.handleRequestDelete(index)} >
                    {data[value]}

                </Chip>
            );
        }
    }

    handleRequestDelete(index) {
        this.state.dataSource[index]['selected'] = false;
        this.setState({dataSource : this.state.dataSource , searchText : '' });
        this.props.selectedOption(this.state.dataSource[index] , this.state.dataSource);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(this.props.dataSource !== nextProps.dataSource) {
            this.setState({ dataSource : nextProps.dataSource });
        }
    }

    getDataSource() {
        return this.state.dataSource.map(data => {
            if(!data.selected) {
                return data
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <AutoComplete
                    floatingLabelText={this.props.floatingLabelText}
                    filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
                    onNewRequest={this.handleNewRequest}
                    searchText={this.state.searchText}
                    dataSource={this.getDataSource()}
                    dataSourceConfig={this.props.dataSourceConfig}
                    openOnFocus={true}
                />
                <div style={this.styles.wrapper}>
                    {this.state.dataSource.map(this.renderChip, this)}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

AutoCompleteHlpr.defaultProps = {
    floatingLabelText : 'Type Something',
    dataSource : [],
    dataSourceConfig : {},
    selectedOption: () => { }
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

**Here is the link to the stackblitz(working online code):**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-svqwcg

---

**How to generate the issue :**

1. Select "Vehicle 1" from first textbox
2. Select "Vehicle 2" from second textbox
3. Select "Vehicle 3" from third textbox

You will get the idea.

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself. I have no idea what this stackblitz website is and I have no intention of visiting it, nor will most of the people who visit this question.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, please visit it once its kind of plunkr, on that site I have created whole demo of issue, there you can see whole project code.

Comment: The problem is that if that website goes down or is otherwise inaccessible for whatever reason this question becomes absolutely meaningless.

Comment: Yes, it is helpful if you do post code, ultimately you will need to do that anyway

Comment: You are using the same state for every field to save values. There is no way to work in another way until You are saving values in the same place.

Comment: @MichalCholewiński, okay , but how its changing state from child to parent,
How AutoCompleteHlpr changing the state of App ?

Comment: I've never used materialized components. But please try to create 3 diffrerent fields in store 
dataSource={this.state.vehicles1} dataSource={this.state.vehicles2} dataSource={this.state.vehicles3}

Comment: That will work I have already tried , but I want to know about this specific situation

Comment: @MichalCholewiński, There is nothing to do with material , all we need is pure react concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that within child components you are mutating parent state. It happens on the line when you change `selected` attribute of item in `vehicles` array:

```
this.state.dataSource[index]['selected'] = true;
```

Mutation is the propagated to all `AutoCompleteHlpr` components, because you are passing the same array to all of them. You are causing situation where in fact you have one global state for all `AutoCompleteHlpr` components.

To fix that you need to pass clone of the `vehicles` array, so then changing props on clone's objects will not affect the origial one. Below you have trivial clone implementation, but you can use another from lodash etc.:

```
const clone = (arg) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arg));
```

In your code you can use it like that:

```
<AutoCompleteHlpr 
          dataSource={clone(this.state.vehicles)} 
          dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}
          floatingLabelText='Select Vehicles'
          selectedOption={this.handleSelectedVehicle}/>
```

Another option is that instead of changing `selected` like

```
this.state.dataSource[index]['selected'] = true;
```

you can do something like:

```
const newDataSource = this.state.dataSource.reduce((ds, item, idx) => index !== idx
   ? ds.concat(item)
   : ds.concat(Object.assign({}, item, { selected: true })), []);
this.setState({ dataSource: newDataSource, searchText: '' });
```

---

**EDIT:** Take a look a the snippet below to see why passing `[...this.state.vehicle]` will not work:

```js
const vehicles = [{value : 1 , label : 'Vehicle 1'},{value : 2 , label : 'Vehicle 2'},{value : 3 , label : 'Vehicle 3'},{value : 4 , label : 'Vehicle 4'},{value : 5 , label : 'Vehicle 5'},{value : 6 , label : 'Vehicle 6'},{value : 7 , label : 'Vehicle 7'},{value : 8 , label : 'Vehicle 8'}];

const vehicles2 = [...vehicles];
console.log(vehicles === vehicles2);
console.log(vehicles[0] === vehicles2[0]);
console.log(vehicles.every((item, idx) => item === vehicles2[idx]))
```

So as you can see, `vehicle` and `vehicle2` are different arrays, but theirs items are references to the same objects! And this is the reason why you need a deep clone.

Comment: Okay, it's working and I have also tried that,so you are just doing is passing clone of vehicle right, so I can also do {...vehicles} in es6 style , right?

Comment: I have also replace the mutation line to var data_source = this.state.dataSource;
data_source[index]['selected'] = true; then it should work right ? but not working

Comment: It is not true that, once we pass the data to child component, it maintains its own state, then how it's changing the parent's state?

Comment: if you will just pass `[...this.state.vehicles]` it will not work since it will reference the same objects as in `this.state.vehicles`. You need to pass deep clone, but this way you are making only shallow copy

Comment: `var data_source = this.state.dataSource; data_source[index]['selected'] = true` this will not work because again you are just reassigning  the array, so you are still mutating `this.state.dataSource`

Comment: What if i use var data_source = this.state.dataSource.slice(); or var data_source = [...this.state.dataSource]; ?

Comment: The problem is that this way you will create new array but with references to  the same object in items!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156470/discussion-between-vivek-doshi-and-andrzej-smyk).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a reference through , so the child component has access to the same vehicles array from the parent component

```
<AutoCompleteHlpr 
          dataSource={this.state.vehicles} 
          dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}
          floatingLabelText='Select Vehicles'
          selectedOption={this.handleSelectedVehicle}
/>
```

You should not mutate it so I'd advise using `Object.assign([],[this.state.vehicles])` if it's not nested down or use `slice` which is not destructive to pass just a copy of it in the `dataSource` prop like so `dataSource = this.state.vehicles.slice()`, there is also the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someobject))` option which is the best option reason being that slice and Object.assign() both give you shallow copies of original object. you can also check out helper libraries like lodash and such

**Note** : All state manipulation should be done only using `this.setState` as stated in the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). Check in your request methods.

Comment: dataSource = this.state.vehicles.slice() , not working

Comment: I have explained why `Object.assign([],[this.state.vehicles])` and `dataSource = this.state.vehicles.slice()` will not work

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk why are they not working if the state is being manipulated properly ?

Comment: if your not mutating array items it should work well then

Comment: @AndrzejSmyk not sure what you mean , the question was how come the child could have changed the parent state . these methods all work perfectly except for Object.assign that can have deep nested issues . mutating array items or not has nothing to do with the issue . @VivekDoshi if by not working you mean the code snippet above , that is because you're mutating state directly and you are missing the `handleSelectedVehicle` method in the parent

Comment: @HamoudSK, the issue is with deepclone , all above function creating shallow copy

Comment: That's true, just because the case here , we have only one level deep I missed the fact that slice also makes a shallow copy .